# Find the place of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list

```
<ul>
    <li class="list_1">a</li>
    <li class="list_2">b</li>
    <li class="list_3">c</li>
    <li class="list_4">d</li>
</ul>
```

This is in a carousel, so that the list items change position (1-2-3-4, 2-3-4-1, 3-4-1-2, 4-1-2-3,...)

How can I find out, using javascript, which item is in, let's say, second and third position?

In the beginning, the `list_2` and `list_3` are in second and third position, after one cycle, the `list_3` and `list_4` are in second and third position, etc.

How to find out what list is in those positions, while I cycle through? For starters I just need to see it displayed in console with `console.log()`, something like:

On 2nd place is list_3, and on third is list_4.

Tried with this but doesn't work:

```
var $list_items = $(this).find('ul li');

$list_items.each(function(i,j){
    $(this).addClass('list_' + (i+1));
console.log($list_items.eq(2).attr('class'));
});
```

I'm using `$(this)` because my original lists are enclosed in a div, and originally lists had no class, so I added them.

Comment: How are you moving them?

Comment: I have carouFredSel.js that manages that.

Comment: If `<li>` positions are changed inside `<ul>`, you can simply use `:eq(1)` inside selector or `.eq(1)` after selector.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use `map()` and `index()` to create an array of the element's class-name and index, obviously this depends on what, *precisely*, you want to find; but your question is somewhat vague on the result you want:

```js
function mapIndices() {
         // iterate over the 'ul li' elements, forming a map:
  return $('ul li').map(function() {
    // returning the className (classes) of the element and its index amongst
    // siblings:
    return this.className + ': ' + $(this).index();
  // converting to an Array:
  }).get();
};

// this is just a simple trigger to move the elements,
// to demonstrate binding the function:
$('#change').on('click', function() {
  var ul = $('ul');
  ul.find('li:first-child').appendTo(ul);
  console.log(mapIndices());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="change">advance positions</button>
<ul>
  <li class="list_1">a</li>
  <li class="list_2">b</li>
  <li class="list_3">c</li>
  <li class="list_4">d</li>
</ul>
```

If, however, you simply want to find out which element is in a specific position:

```js
$('#change').on('click', function() {
  var ul = $('ul');
  ul.find('li:first-child').appendTo(ul);
  // bear in mind that JavaScript has zero-based indexing,
  // 2 is the index of third element, not the second:
  console.log(ul.find('li').eq(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="change">advance positions</button>
<ul>
  <li class="list_1">a</li>
  <li class="list_2">b</li>
  <li class="list_3">c</li>
  <li class="list_4">d</li>
</ul>
```

References:

- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: This last thing is what I need, but I seem to have problems with it :\

Answer (score 0):

**Array manipulation:**

```js
var arr = $('li').get();            // http://api.jquery.com/get/
// var arr = ["aa","bb","cc","dd"]; // you can try also using this guy

function doIt(){
   if(this.id==="next") arr.push(  arr.shift() );  // send first to last
                   else arr.unshift( arr.pop() );  // send last to first
   $('ul').html( arr );
}
    
$('#prev, #next').on('click', doIt);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="prev">PREV</button>
<button id="next">NEXT</button>
  
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>-----------</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

First give an id/class to the ul:

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li class="list_1">a</li>
    <li class="list_2">b</li>
    <li class="list_3">c</li>
    <li class="list_4">d</li>
</ul>
```

Using jQuery to access the 'li' element at 2nd position:

```
var second_li = $('#mylist').find('li')[1]; // to access 2nd li use index 1
var second_li_class = $(second_li).attr('class'); // second_li_class will be equal to 'list_2'
var second_li_content = $(second_li).html(); // second_li_content will be equal to 'b'
```